# Azure Data Factory - No Output in Select Transformation - Mapping Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am reading an excel file and applying some transformations.
I am not able to find any data from Select transformer in Data Preview.

[image]

But the previous "FromNumericLen" transformer outputs data and can find the same in Data Preview.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind pasting the script behind from your data flow? You can find it from the Script button on top of the data flow designer.

Comment: It is working after enabling Allow Schema drift in the Source transformer.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment thread, the fix is to enable Allow Schema Drift in the Source transform.